# Javascript Object formatting

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

```
[
   [
       {"path":"path2","value":"kkk"},
       {"path":"path0","value":"uuu"},
       {"path":"path1","value":"ppp"}
   ]
]
```

I get above result from for my manipulation, But I need it as follows.

```
["path":"path2","value":"kkk"],
["path":"path0","value":"uuu"],
["path":"path1","value":"ppp"]
```

Here is my code:

```
$scope.sharePaths[d.id] = []
d.conf.paths = []
$scope.sharePaths[d.id][index] = []

commaPath = 'kkk,uuu,ppp'
a = commaPath.split(',')
for key of a
  value = a[key]
  $scope.sharePaths[d.id][index].push {'path':'path'+key, 'value':a[key]}
  d.conf.paths.push {'path':'path'+key, 'value':a[key]}
```

Comment: your expected result is invalid structure

Comment: your second line looks strange wouldn't you want it to be:
[{"path":"path2","value":"kkk"},{"path":"path0","value":"uuu"},{"path":"path1","value":"ppp"}]

Comment: @David yes, pls let me know how to do it?

Comment: well the push statement needs to be wrapped with brackets

.push({'path':'path'+key, 'value':a[key]});

also what does the value of "a" look like?

Comment: There is really no need to change it, just use the first element of the array instead of the whole array. if your output is `data` ...then `data[0]` is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @David like, ["kkk", "uuu", "ppp"]

Comment: I would suggest looking at Jeff's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the first element of your array.  The variable `data` is already formatted correctly.  The new format you want is not valid JSON.

```
var data = [[{"path":"path2","value":"kkk"},{"path":"path0","value":"uuu"},{"path":"path1","value":"ppp"}]];

data = data[0];
```

Comment: No still it return the entire,